# Maven error "maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor"

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, java-8

I ran through Maven Run configurations with clean install and got following error, am unable to proceed further

```
[INFO] -----------------< com.bhg.qa:sfdc-BHG-LeadManagement >-----------------
[INFO] Building bhg 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.498 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-04T08:11:54-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): proxy.javacodegueeks.com: Unknown host proxy.javacodegueeks.com -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Same code is working for my team members without any issues.

Comment: Do you have proxy configured? `Unknown host proxy.javacodegueeks.com`

Comment: There is a proxy configured which does not work: `proxy.javacodegueeks.com: Unknown host proxy.javacodegueeks.com`